# Org agenda - toggle TODO state backwards?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In org agenda mode, pressing `t` advances the TODO state of the item one step forward (to the next TODO keyword in order).

How can I add a binding to move the TODO state backwards by one step? I have a setup with several states, and advancing one step too far is very annoying as I have to toggle all states until I restore the previous state.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `org-use-fast-todo-selection` and define shortcut keys to your TODO states. Then when you hit `t` in your agenda you'll be prompted for a second character to pick the specific TODO state you want.

I believe fast selection is enabled by default, so you may just need to tweak the definition of your TODO states. See [Fast access to TODO states](http://orgmode.org/manual/Fast-access-to-TODO-states.html#Fast-access-to-TODO-states) in the org manual for more -- you can either configure your `org-todo-states` globally or use the in-buffer `#TODO` setting,

With the default bindings, that would allow you to use `t` followed by another key to jump to a specific state; or you can use `C-S-left` and `C-S-right` to switch states according to the defined sequence.

Answer (score 5):

`org-agenda-todo-previousset` should do what you want by shifting the TODO state backwards.  From the docstring:

> Switch TODO entry to previous sequence.

By default it's bound to <kbd>C-S-left</kbd>.  You can set it to a different binding with

`(require 'org-agenda) (define-key org-agenda-mode-map "y" 'org-agenda-todo-previousset)`

which would set <kbd>y</kbd> to call the function (note <kbd>y</kbd> is already bound to `org-agenda-year-view` by default, you may want to choose another key).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not accurate. Given this setting: `(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO" "PENDING" "NEXT" "DOING" "|" "VERIFY" "DONE" "DELEGATED")))`, and the state of `DOING`, `C-S-<left>` resets the state to `TODO`...